# How do I use FileDialog to create a directory, then automatically copy files to new directory?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my program, I would like to use a FileDialog to access audio files, then automatically copy the selected file(s) to a new folder upon clicking "open". I want to do this so I can make changes to a sample without changing the original file.

My problem is that whenever I select a file then click "open" in the file dialog, the program crashes or closes.

```
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav;";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            bool directoryExists = Directory.Exists(@"C:\Documents\LUX\Soundbites\");
            if (directoryExists == true)
            {
                string[] files = open.FileNames;

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                                            
                    var info = new FileInfo(file);                          

                    File.Copy(file, @"C:\Documents\LUX\Soundbites\", true);
                }
            }

            if (directoryExists != true)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Documents\LUX\");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Documents\LUX\Soundbites\");
                string[] files = open.FileNames;

                foreach (string file in files)
                {
                                            
                    var info = new FileInfo(file);    

                    File.Copy(file, @"C:\Documents\LUX\Soundbites\", true);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm sure this is a common operation, but I'm new to developing and I haven't found any real answers online.

Comment: You always must run your application in Debug mode. If you had, you would get an exception message that tells you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: Also, to get the current user's document folder, prefer `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`. You should always create temporary files in the official Temp folder, which you get from `Path.GetTempPath()`. And don't forget to clean up when done. And be prepared that the machine your code runs on does not have sufficient space on the system drive.

Answer (score 0):

*File.Copy*'s second argument requires you a file name for which the file will be copied to, not a directory, in your *File.Copy* codes, change it to this:

```
File.Copy(file, @"C:\Documents\LUX\Soundbites\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file), true);
```